# Checking if the time is within a specific range in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to automate a tracking sheet that tracks accurate hours of equipment per task performed.

For simplicity, let's assume that we got the following tables for tasks and equipment:

Tasks table:

| Task | Description | Assigned Hours |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | something here | [USERINPUT] |

Equipment Table:

| Equipment | Start Time | End Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| equip1 | 7:00:00 AM | 9:00:00 AM |

The assigned hours uses the following code to get the user input:

```
For i = 1 To numProduction

    hoursAssigned = InputBox(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("E" & i + 47).Value,    "Assign hours to the following task", 1)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("H" & i + 47).Value = hoursAssigned

Next i
```

So let's say that the user inputted 1 hour for this task. The outcome should be as follows:

| Task | Equipment | Start Time | End Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | equip1 | 7:00:00 AM | 8:00:00 AM |

I tried to use the following code, but it doesn't work and I am not sure how to approach

```
For e = 26 To 46 'this is the specific range of cells that the equipment gets exported from another excel         
    equip = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("B" & e).Value                
    startTime = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("F" & e).Value                
    endTime = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("H" & e).Value                                
    
    remainingHours = endTime - startTime                                
    
    If Not equip = "" Then                                        
        For j = 48 To rowData ' rowData is the final row the data is                       
            phasecode = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("B" & j).Value 'task column                      
            phasecodeAssignedHours = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("H" & j).Value / 24 'assigned hours
            Equipment = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("data").Range("B" & e).Value                                                
            
            'this the part of the code that i am trying to figure out
            usualStartTime = 7 / 24                        
            addedHours = usualStartTime + phasecodeAssignedHours                                                
            If startTime <= usualStartTime And endTime >= addedHours Then                            
                MsgBox (startTime * 24 & Chr(10) & endTime * 24)                                
            End If                                                                                                
            
            'my code that places the result into the excel here
            'my code that formats the placement here
        Next j
    End If                             
Next e
```

**Edit 1:**

@CDP1802 The imported tables are a little bit more detailed than the ones I described in my problem, but here they are:

Date:

[image]

Employee:
[image]

Equipment:
[image]

Production (tasks):
[image]

The equipment section gets analyzed into the following on another page called "EquipmentResults":
[image]

**Edit 2:** Please check edit 3 for a more in-depth explanation, although it does use a different example.

Please bare with my poor English and weak description of the question. I will try to clarify even more in the comments if needed.

Table 1: (This table is imported, and gets placed in worksheet "Data")

| Name | Total Hours | Start Time | End Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Equipment 1 | 2 | 7:00:00 AM | 9:00:00 AM |
| Equipment 2 | 8 | 9:00:00 AM | 5:00:00 PM |
| Equipment 3 | 10 | 7:00:00 AM | 5:00:00 PM |

Table 2: (This table is imported, and gets placed in worksheet "Data")

| Task # | Description | Quantatity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.000 | task 1 description | 5 |
| 2.000 | task 2 description | 15 |

I have made a code that turns the previous two tables into the following table:

| Task # | Date | Name | Start Time | End Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.000 | 01/20/2021 | Equipment 1 | 7:00:00 AM | 9:00:00 AM |
| 2.000 | 01/20/2021 | Equipment 1 | 7:00:00 AM | 9:00:00 AM |
| 1.000 | 01/20/2021 | Equipment 2 | 9:00:00 AM | 5:00:00 PM |
| 2.000 | 01/20/2021 | Equipment 2 | 9:00:00 AM | 5:00:00 PM |
| 1.000 | 01/20/2021 | Equipment 3 | 7:00:00 AM | 5:00:00 PM |
| 2.000 | 01/20/2021 | Equipment 3 | 7:00:00 AM | 5:00:00 PM |

I am struggling to make it turn into this table though (which should be the result):

| Task # | Date | Name | Start Time | End Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.000 | 01/20/2021 | Equipment 1 | 7:00:00 AM | 9:00:00 AM |
| 2.000 | 01/20/2021 | Equipment 1 | 9:00:00 AM | 9:00:00 AM |
| 1.000 | 01/20/2021 | Equipment 2 | 9:00:00 AM | 2:00:00 PM |
| 2.000 | 01/20/2021 | Equipment 2 | 2:00:00 PM | 5:00:00 PM |
| 1.000 | 01/20/2021 | Equipment 3 | 7:00:00 AM | 12:00:00 PM |
| 2.000 | 01/20/2021 | Equipment 3 | 12:00:00 PM | 5:00:00 PM |

**Edit 3**:
[image]

[image]

Comment: What would the outcome be if the user input 3 hours for the task ?

Comment: It should be start time of 7:00:00 AM and end time of 9:00:00 AM and have a remaining hour of 1 hour to be used on other tasks if existent

Comment: What if the user types an alpha character into the InputBox?

Comment: @braX, the code will break because it is dependant on the number of hours as an integer.

Comment: Probably should check to see if it's numeric first then?

Comment: If a task requires equipment for 3 hours and the equipment is only available for 2 hours each day then isn't the outcome 2 lines,1 line 7am to 9am and another line 7am to 8am.

Comment: @CDP1802 Knowing the scenarios, you'd never have equipment working more hours than the total assigned hours per task. All the scenarios are as follows: 1. equipment hours are less than the total assigned hours, which is the case that is presented in the quetsion. 2. equipment hours are more than the total assigned hours, therefore it should move onto the next task and assign that task the remaining hours of that equipment. Would you like me to make more tables so that the conditions/scenarios are more clear?

Comment: @braX I will focus on optimizing the code after getting to work first. I am not too worried about user input being false.

Comment: Can out add the Dim statements for the variables and the column letters and row numbers to your tables.

Comment: @CDP1802 I have uploaded the tables as requested. The first few tables are all on a single page called "Data", the last one is on a page called "Equipment Result". My code doesn't utilize the number of hours used in assigned phase code hours, it just pastes the values as is and doesn't take into account the remaining hours either. So if there are multiple tasks that day, it will keep putting 7:00:00 AM to 9:00:00 AM regardless. (Which is what I am trying to find in this question). I hope this makes it a little bit more clear, but if you have any more questions, I am more than happy to clarify.

Comment: I am having difficulty matching your explanation to the data. In the example you have 1 task with assigned hours of 10. So in that case there are no remaining hours. Also you say "multiple tasks that day" so how are tasks allocated to a date ?. The only date I can see is in cell B1 and that is not used in your code. Could you expand the example to show 2  or more tasks (with allocated hours less than some of the equipment hours) and then in the EquipmentResults  table show where the remaining hours should go to.

Comment: @CDP1802 Sorry for the delay in response, I have posted another example hoping it clarifies the proceess a little bit. Basically, I want the code to go through every task and assign it hours. based on the assigned hours it would determine the number of hours the equipment worked on that task. so if a task took 7 hours to complete, and the equipment was only active for 2hours, then it would check if the 2 hours the equipment worked is within the 7 hours and then assign 2 hours.

Comment: @CDP1802 similarly if a piece of equipment worked 1 hour, then it would check in which duration of the task that fits, and then place it in that time. The difficult scenarios are all if statements to make sure the conditions pass if there are remaining hours passing over to other tasks.

Comment: @CDP1802 I have just added an explanation in edit3, I hope this clarifies it even more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 2 tables on your data sheet like this. Name them Table1 for equipment and Table2 for tasks

[image]

If the assigned hours is blank it will prompt you for values. The results are written to sheet `EquipmentResults`

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ProcessData()

    Dim wb As Workbook, wsData As Worksheet, wsOut As Worksheet
    Dim tb1 As ListObject, tb2 As ListObject, rng As Range
    Dim TaskTitle As String, sTaskHrs As String, s As String
    Dim dt As Date, arTask, arEquip
    Dim r As Long, e As Long, t As Long
  
    ' assign hours to tasks
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsData = wb.Sheets("Data")
    Set tb2 = wsData.ListObjects("Table2") ' tasks
    For Each rng In tb2.DataBodyRange.Rows
        TaskTitle = rng.Cells(1, 1) & vbCrLf & rng.Cells(1, 2)
        If IsEmpty(rng.Cells(1, 3)) Then
            s = InputBox("Enter Hours for Task " & TaskTitle, "Task Hrs")
            If IsNumeric(s) Then rng.Cells(1, 3) = s
        End If
    Next
    arTask = tb2.DataBodyRange.Value2
    
    ' get date from cell B2
    dt = wsData.Range("B2").Value2
  
    ' generate Equipment Results
    Dim taskStart As Date, taskEnd As Date, taskDur As Single
    Dim equipStart As Date, equipEnd As Date, remain As Single
    Dim prevTaskEnd As Date
  
    Set wsOut = wb.Sheets("EquipmentResults")
    wsOut.Cells.Clear
    With wsOut.Range("A1:E1")
        .Value2 = Array("TAsk #", "Date", "Name", "Start Time", "End Time")
        .Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200)
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
  
    r = 2
    Set tb1 = wsData.ListObjects("Table1") ' Equip
    arEquip = tb1.DataBodyRange.Value2
    ' each equip
    For e = 1 To UBound(arEquip)
        
        equipStart = DateAdd("n", arEquip(e, 2) * 24 * 60, dt)
        equipEnd = DateAdd("n", arEquip(e, 3) * 24 * 60, dt)
        remain = 0
  
        'each task
        For t = 1 To UBound(arTask)
            taskDur = arTask(t, 3)
            
            ' was there spare hours on last task
            If remain > 0 Then
                taskStart = prevTaskEnd
            Else
                remain = 0
                taskStart = equipStart ' normal start time
            End If
             
            ' calculate task end
            taskEnd = DateAdd("h", taskDur, taskStart)
  
            ' does task end before equipment
            remain = DateDiff("h", taskEnd, equipEnd)
            If remain < 0 Then
                taskEnd = equipEnd
            End If

            ' result
            With wsOut
               .Cells(r, 1) = arTask(t, 1) ' task
               .Cells(r, 2) = dt ' date
               .Cells(r, 3) = arEquip(e, 1) ' equipment name
               .Cells(r, 4) = taskStart ' date
               .Cells(r, 5) = taskEnd ' date
            End With
            prevTaskEnd = taskEnd
            r = r + 1
        Next
    Next

    ' Sort data by equip, task
    With wsOut.Sort
        With .SortFields
            .Clear
            .Add Key:=wsOut.Range("A2:A" & r), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
               Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Add Key:=wsOut.Range("C2:C" & r), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
               Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        End With
        .SetRange wsOut.Range("A1:E" & r)
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    wsOut.Columns("D:E").NumberFormat = "hh:mm AM/PM" '"m/d/yyyy h:mm"
    wsOut.Columns("A:E").AutoFit
    MsgBox r & " rows written to " & wsOut.Name, vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Ah, this is code is a little bit more advanced than what I know, it'll take me a little bit of time to digest it and understand it fully (I am a beginner at programming). This code worked fine, but I was wondering how would you adjust it to track employee hours as well? It is primarily the same process, the only difference is to identify if they started earlier than the usual start time, ended before the calculated end time, had their lunch break (which is always from 12:00:00 PM to 12:30:00 PM. If the time goes through the lunch break, then it should add 30 minutes to that task.